# add class to element in viewport

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

I have five sections on my page, and I am trying to add class "active" to the section in the view port.
I tried this code but it is not working properly.
the code saves all elements with tag name "section" in a node list then created an array of this list, I looped over the array and added an event listener for each element, then I tested if the element is in the viewport is so I add the class else I remove the class.
the problem is once the page is scrolled all the five sections will have the class "active" which means that multiple elements have the class "active" at the same time even though only one section is viewed in the port and when I keep on scrolling down the sections that are moved upward out of the viewport have their class "active" removed.
how can i have one element with the class "active"[image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HOlp.jpg) at a time?

```
//values of viewport
const viewWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
const viewHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

//set class active to section in viewport
function sectionInView(x) {
    for (let i = 0; i in x; i++) {
        document.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
            let el = x[i].getBoundingClientRect();
            if (el.top >= 0 && el.left >= 0 && el.bottom <= viewHeight && el.right <= viewWidth) {
                x[i].setAttribute("class", "active your-active-class");

            }
            else {

                x[i].removeAttribute("class", "active your-active-class");
            }
        });
    }
}
sectionInView(sectionListArray);
```

Comment: It's a very strange behavior. Why don't you wait the user to open the section he is interested in instead of opening/closing sections depending on the viewport?

Comment: why not use `classList.add()` and `classList.remove()` instead of `setAttribute`?

Comment: @Azu it is a requirement in a project i am working on

Comment: @tacoshy would it change the behaviour of the code?

Comment: Have you investigated IntersectionObserver?

Comment: no it is just way cleaner as that is the actual way to add, remove or toggle classes on elements.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let sectionListArray = document.querySelectorAll('section')
const viewHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
         window.onscroll = (() => {
            sectionListArray.forEach(function(v) {
                let rect = v.getBoundingClientRect();
                let y = rect.y;
                let bottom = rect.bottom;
                let height = rect.height;
                if (y > viewHeight|| bottom+height < viewHeight ) {
                    v.classList.add('active')
                } else {
                    v.classList.remove('active')
                }
            })
        })
```

```css
section {
            height: 300px;
            background: red;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            transition: 1s;
            opacity:1
        }
.active{
opacity:0
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
```